# Why are C arrays declared as int arr[] instead of int []arr?

Tags: c, arrays

Java supports both, so why not C?

I think `int []arr` is easier to read.

Is there a special reason?

Comment: Because the language has been designed like this. And "easy to read" is subject to interpretation. And C is not Java.

Comment: And why can't you use pointers in Java? Shouldn't the language support them?

Comment: `int []arr` is very ugly. `int[] arr` (like in Java) - better.

Comment: IIRC, the reason is that Dennis Richie wanted the declaration to mimic the use. Hence int *foo and int bar[somesize]. He's written about this on his web site.

Comment: Why do we say "good" in English instead of "gut", like in German?  I think "gut" looks better.  Is there any special reason?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that C declarations were designed such that [declaration follows usage](https://eigenstate.org/notes/c-decl).

If you declare a variable like so:

```
int x[5];
```

Usage of `x` looks very similar to its declaration:

```
int foo = x[0];
```

The same applies to pointers:

```
int *y;
```

Usage of `y` also looks similar to its declaration:

```
int foo = *y; /* Dereference the pointer y */
```

This also applies to much more complicated declarations like so:

```
int **z[3][4]; /* z as in array of 3 arrays of 4 pointers to pointers to ints */

int foo = **z[0][0]; /* Fetch the first element of z, then fetch the first
                        element of the resulting array, then dereference that
                        pointer value, then dereference that pointer value */
```

And also works for function declarations / pointer-to-function declarations:

```
int (*f)(); /* f is a pointer to a function returning int */

int foo = (*f)();  /* Dereference the pointer f, then call it as a function. */
```

Answer (score 4):

Java borrowed from C not the other way round.

Obviously java decided that would be an improvement over the C syntax.

However, generally the more ways you can define something, the harder it is for the compiler to parse the code. As `c` was developed in the 1970's, with limited computing power, simplicity would have been high on their list of requirements.

In the 1990's, when they developed Java, this would have been much less of a worry.